# Generic method for not related objects - java

Tags: java, generics

I have following two classes:

```
public Class A{
    String name;
    Integer age;

    //setters and getters
}
```

And

```
public Class B{
    String name;
    Integer age;
    Integer height;

    //setters and getters
}
```

and following method

```
public String getMyName(B b){
    return b.getName()+" "+b.getAge()+" "+b.getHeight();
}
```

**Is it possible to refactor this method to use generics which will allow me to call it for objects of those two different classes?**

E.g

```
public <T> String getMyName(T t){
    return t.getName()+" "+t.getAge()+( t instanceof B ? " "+t.getHeight() : "");
}
```

Of course it doesn't work since `t` doesn't *know* methods `getName`, `getAge` and `getHeight`.

Classes are not in any relation( I know that they can inherit from one common class and use `<T extends C>` but they don't have superclass or common interface)

Comment: No it is not possible in this case.

Comment: You could you're own interfaces with the `getName()` and `getAge()` methods and make A and B implement it.

Comment: Well you have to relate them somehow. Add an interface

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, without using a common interface or superclass this is not possible with generics. You could use reflection but I'd advice against that and suggest providing a common interface instead.

As others said, there would be other ways to handle that case (e.g. method overloading or passing `Object` and using `instanceof` and casts) but if you can use a common interface, I'd still go that way.

Note that Java generics are unlinke C++ generics/templates which would allow what you want to do - and there are good reasons for that difference.

Answer (score 2):

This is the place where people shout  the line [`Programming with interfaces`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface-based_programming).

Take a an interface and add common methods to it and create a generic method which takes that interface as a argument.

That makes your life easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `instanceof` to check whether is compatible type and if it is, cast object to your type and call methods. It is not elegant way, but still. So this way, you can use your method as generic. :)

Comment: As you say, not elegant at all. Without inheritance nor interface any solution looks like a mess and makes a conceptual error :)

Comment: yep, i agree that it should be used with polymorphism, but the OP needs any solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically adapt them on the fly - something like:

```
public class A {

    String name;
    Integer age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}

public class B {

    String name;
    Integer age;
    Integer height;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public Integer getHeight() {
        return height;
    }
}

// Create a common interface.
public interface AorB {

    public String getName();

    public Integer getAge();

    // Use Java 8 to implant a default getHeight if it is missing.
    default Integer getHeight() {
        return 0;
    }
}

// Dynamicaly adapt each type.
public String getMyName(A a) {
    // Adapt it on the fly.
    return getMyName(new AorB() {

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return a.getName();
        }

        @Override
        public Integer getAge() {
            return a.getAge();
        }

    });
}

public String getMyName(B b) {
    // Adapt it on the fly.
    return getMyName(new AorB() {

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return b.getName();
        }

        @Override
        public Integer getAge() {
            return b.getAge();
        }

        @Override
        public Integer getHeight() {
            return b.getHeight();
        }

    });
}

// Your method almost untouched.
public String getMyName(AorB ab) {
    return ab.getName() + " " + ab.getAge() + " " + ab.getHeight();
}

public void test() {
    A a = new A();
    a.name = "A";
    a.age = 10;

    B b = new B();
    b.name = "B";
    b.age = 10;
    b.height = 12;

    System.out.println("A:" + getMyName(a));
    System.out.println("B:" + getMyName(b));
}
```

I am using Java-8 `default` here to implement a default `getHeight` but it would not take much effort to eliminate that - you would need to implement a `getHeight` for the `getMyName(A)` method.

Sadly - of course - this is not using generics in the solution so you may see this as *not an answer to your question* but it is an *alternate solution to your problem* so I chose to post.