# Cast a generic type in input a method to set a specific property in common between two classes

Tags: java, generics, casting

My first post here - I hope to give you all info required.
I tried to check online anmd in forum but I cannot find the same case - maybe is not possible -.-'

This is my situation:

I have two classes with same properties **(I cannot change it, add an interface or abstract class)**

```
public class InputA {
  private String status;
  private String name;
  ....
}
public class InputB {
  private String status;
  private String name;
  ....
}

private <T> VerifyRequest createVerifyRequest(T input) {

   if (input instanceof InputA)
      input = (InputA) input;
   if (input instanceof InputB)
    input = (InputB) input;

    VerifyRequest request = new VerifyRequest;
    verifyRequest.setStatus (input.getStatus());
    ....
    ....
    ....
    return request;
}
```

My idea is to cast because I know only two different type are possible.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for your support ^^

---

I tried to pass Object too

```
private VerifyRequest createVerifyRequest(Object input) {

   if (input instanceof InputA)
      input = (InputA) input
   if (input instanceof InputB)
    input = (InputB) input;

    VerifyRequest request = new VerifyRequest;
    verifyRequest.setStatus (input.getStatus()); //this give me error  (Cannot resolve getStatus in Object)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generic method for not related objects - java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25061494/generic-method-for-not-related-objects-java)

Comment: Thanks Eritran. In answer I read "As others said, there would be other ways to handle that case (e.g. method overloading or passing Object and using instanceof and casts)" So is it possible to do it. Am I casting wrong? I tried with Object too  (added to message)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input` is of type `T` so you can't cast it to `InputA` or `InputB`. You could do something like below but it is not that elegant:

```
private <T> VerifyRequest createVerifyRequest(T input) {
    VerifyRequest request = new VerifyRequest();

    if (input instanceof InputA){
        InputA a = (InputA) input;
        request.setStatus (a.getStatus());
    } 
    else if (input instanceof InputB){
        InputB b = (InputB) input;
        request.setStatus (b.getStatus());
    }

    return request;
}
```

Comment: From Java 16 onwards you could simplify that with "instanceof pattern matching" - `if (input instanceof InputA a)` and eventually even further with "switch pattern matching" - still in preview)